# Firebase Data not showing in App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am slightly new to Firebase implementation, and would appreciate any help in the display of my Firebase data in my Android application. There are no specifics in "what data" should be displayed, I am simply attempting to populate the entire database into the application. There are also NOT specific user auth's, the database is shared by all users for the sake of this application.

Here is my Cart.java (Where I would like the data to populate)

```
    package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apptt2163;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class sunglass1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String TAG;
    int minteger = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sunglass2);


            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addcart);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Octagon Glasses");

                    myRef.setValue("$64");

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Added to Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewcart);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openCart();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openCart() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, cart.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


}}
```

Here is the cart.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my cartadapter.java:

```
   package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apptt2163;

    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class cartadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<cartadapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<cartitems> cartList;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView title, price;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            }
        }


        public cartadapter(List<cartitems> moviesList) {
            this.cartList = moviesList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.cart_list_row, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            cartitems items = cartList.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(items.getTitle());
            holder.price.setText(items.getPrice());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return cartList.size();
        }
    }
```

And of course, cartitems.java:

```
 package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apptt2163;

public class cartitems {

    private String title, price;


    public cartitems() {
    }

    public cartitems(String title, String price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String year) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Here is the cart_list_row.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/row_padding_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/title"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="Your Cart"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/title"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for absolutely any help,

Comment: If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't use authentication and no error(or Exception) comes then i think you must set auth == null in firebase console database rule part.and if you also done it then check variable name of the class cartitems should same as firebase variable.